# C++ storing data from txt into variables using delimiter

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am doing some debugging and i realised that is something wrong the reading of data. I am trying to store data read from a txt into different variables using delimiter.

data.txt

```
homer:mtrjw:member:0
bryan:gw~fs:member:0
adam:fifr:member:0
admin12:firns67:admin:0
```

code:

```
string user, pwd, role;
string lock;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("data.txt");

while(inFile.good()){

    getline(inFile, user, ':');
    getline(inFile, pwd, ':');
    getline(inFile, role, ':');
    getline(inFile, lock, ':');

    cout << user << " " << pwd << " " << role << " " << lock << " " << endl;
    /*
    some if conditions...
    }*/
}
```

output:

```
homer mtrjw member 0
bryan 
gw~fs member 0
adam fifr 
member 0
admin12 firns67 admin 
0
taken yfpjs member 0
brian 
gwnfs member 1
miller rnqqjw 
member 0
 1
miller rnqqjw
```

As you can see the output only the 1st line is being stored properly and display, second line onwards is all wrong. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Add delimiters to your output: "cout << "user: " << user << " pwd: " << ...". Your values are not where you think they are.

Comment: nope doesnt make a different i only cout to see data, is still wrong

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. Adding delimiters will point you towards the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider there are two problems:
The first one is that you're looking for the **:** four times. But when it's the fourth time you should expect **'\n'**, because **':'** will be met only after *bryan*:

```
string user, pwd, role;
string lock;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("data.txt");

while(inFile.good()){
getline(inFile, user, ':');
getline(inFile, pwd, ':');
getline(inFile, role, ':');
getline(inFile, lock, '\n');

cout << user << " " << pwd << " " << role << " " << lock << " " << endl;
/*
some if conditions...
}*/
```

}

The second one is your '\n' in this case becomes the part of the *lock*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
  getline(inFile, lock, ':');
```

to

```
  getline(inFile, lock);
```

When you use the first form, it reads the `0` from the first line, the newline, and everything up to the first `:` in the second line and puts it in `lock`.